# Conversion Issue Pine script Version 2 to Version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I found this pine script Version 2 code; in line 9 of the code variable k is declared it references itself on same line! don't know how to convert this code; I would really appreciate any help. Thank You.

```
//@version=2
study("Pseudo Polynomial Channel",overlay=true)
length = input(14),morph = input(0.9,minval=0,maxval=1),mult = input(1.),flatten = input(1.)
//----
x = n
y = close
m(a,b) =>
    p = morph * a + (1-morph) * b
k = nz(m(k[length],y),y) + (x-x[length])/(x[length*2]-x[length]) * (nz(m(k[length*2],y),y) - 
     nz(m(k[length],y),y))/flatten
k1 = sma(k,length)
er = cum(abs(y-k1))/n * mult
//----
a = k1 + er
b = k1 - er
//----
A = plot(a,color=#2196f3,linewidth=2,transp=0)
plot(k1,color=#e65100,linewidth=2,transp=0)
B = plot(b,color=#ff1100,linewidth=2,transp=0)
fill(A,B,#2196f3,transp=95)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define it first then assign the new value with the `:=` operator.

```
k = 0.0
k := nz(m(k[length],y),y) + (x-x[length])/(x[length*2]-x[length]) * (nz(m(k[length*2],y),y) - 
     nz(m(k[length],y),y))/flatten
```